# Xquery to save data in a XML file

Tags: xquery, basex

Following is the XML structure -

```
<Documents>
 <Doc n="Name1" year="2010">
 .....
 </Doc>
 <Doc n="Name2" year="2010">
 .....
 </Doc>
 <Doc n="Name3" year="2011">
 .....
 </Doc>
 <Doc n="Name4" year="2011">
 .....
 </Doc>
```

I am using BaseX to store this document. I need to extract
some data from this and store it as a xml file. Say, I need a separate
xml file for years.

How to get this done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using BaseX, please visit this link -

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:append

```
for $x in doc('DBNAME')//Doc
  where $x/@year eq '2010'
  return file:append("C:\2010.xml", $x)
```

This query will extract the required data in file named 2010.xml in C drive. File name and location can be changed as per you requirement.

Using above query you will have change the year value `2010` as required. If you have year with different values and in order, as I see from the structure, you can use following query. This query will create multiple files, for all the years.

```
for $year in (2010 to 2011)
  (: Year are specified :)
  let $fName := concat("C:\", $year, "B.xml")
  (: The path is created and stored in $fName variable :)
  for $x in doc('docs')//Doc
    where $x/@year eq xs:string($year)
    return file:append($fName, $x)
```

I hope both the examples are quite self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one is the best suitable answer as per my need.